# Search and Replace random cell text by first :

Tags: excel, text, replace, cell

I have a slew of rows (100K+) to search and modify the contents.

For example the cells contain similiar text as DGC9610411:DB:10:82

All of this text can change per row except that fact that the : means something to me.

In this and every other row,  i need to remove the first : and all the text after so that the cell would look like this   DGC9610411

Next I will be adding the contents of another cell to the end.    I think that will be an easy step and I could most likely figure that out without much effort.

I have this code in a while loop for each row. so the code is looking at one row at a time.

I have searched but everyone seems to have a different set of needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use Find and Replace, no need for vba or formulas.

1. Select the column containing the data that you need to modify
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>h</kbd> to open the Find and Replace dialog.
3. In the "Find what:" field, type `:*`
4. In the "Replace with:" field, leave it blank
5. Click <kbd>Replace All</kbd>

[image: tigeravatar Find and Replace]

*EDIT:* If it has to be VBA, this simple macro will accomplish the same thing. Be sure to change the `A` to your actual column letter.

```
Sub tgr()

    Columns("A").Replace ":*", ""

End Sub
```

*EDIT:* Upon request I am adding a formula solution.  In cell B1 and copied down:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(":",A1&":")-1)
```

Comment: Very Nice!  I did not realize the Replace method supports wildcards.

Comment: Yeah, could do the same thing in VBA if you really wanted to: `Columns("A").Replace ":*", ""`

Comment: I had to use VBA as there are a slew of other commands that I am doing with this data.    I check this is the right answer as I used your second suggestion         Columns("A").Replace ":*", ""  worked great.   THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

Try this small macro:

```
Sub colonoscopy()
    Dim c As String
    Dim r As Range, I As Long
    For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        v = r.Value
        I = InStr(1, v, ":")
        If I > 0 Then
            r.Value = Mid(v, 1, I - 1)
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```